# GKE cluster upgrade

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, upgrade

Need to perform K8s(GKE) version upgrade from 1.27 to 1.28 and 1.28 to 1.29 with application deployed. Determine the best variables for a successful upgrade with minimum service down time.Variables include but not limit to maxSurge and maxUnavailable.Can anybody help me with step by step process on how to do this upgrade activity?

Comment: Consider to ask sys-admin questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to initially check which APIs have been deprecated in successive versions 1.28 and 1.27 [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/deprecations/apis-1-27), some more info [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/deprecations).

Additionally, if you have any Java-based workloads, there is a change in the cgroup. Upgrading the cluster to 1.28 activates cgroup v2. Please refer to this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud/articles/78129451/the-upgrade-to-gke-1-26-activates-cgroup-v2-causing-disruptions-to-java-based). Also you can change your node pool upgrade strategy from Surge upgrades to Blue-green upgrades, here existing nodes are kept available for rolling back while the workloads are validated on the new node configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Google automatically upgrades clusters and nodes. To have more control over the auto-upgrades your cluster and its nodes receive, you can enroll it in a [release channel](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/release-channels). All Autopilot clusters are automatically enrolled in a release channel.

To discover more about managing your cluster's GKE version, refer to the Upgrades [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/upgrades#automatic_cp_upgrades).

Please refer to the provided [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/upgrading-a-cluster#upgrade_cp) for detailed instructions on how to manually initiate an upgrade at any time once a new version becomes available.

Comment: not using autopilot one, using standard cluster here. Thanks for your valuable links you have shared

Comment: I have my gke cluster which is standard one not autopilot and control plane is enrolled in Release Channel[stable]. Now I have upgraded my control plane from 1.27 to 1.28 and once its done I have upgraded Node Pool from 1.27 to 1.28. Post upgrade applications are runnning fine, but in the console I can see one notoification just beside my cluster name . Its written "can't scale up nodes". what does it mean? Though my cluster has been upgraded successsfully . And master node upgrade took 24 min and node pool upgrade took 2h20min. Is it okay ? waiting for your answer.

Comment: Can't scale up nodes generally imply that something is blocking the nodes from scaling up. Would you please share the logs? If you just clicked on the details besides the error message, you would see. A screenshot would be appreciated.

That warning has nothing to do with upgrades, both are different.  logs would reveal much info so awaiting

Comment: I would also like to add that when you review your logs, you will likely see one of the scale up errors listed here.https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-autoscaler-visibility#scaleup-errors

Comment: Do you have any notifications or warning on your console, @Schatt?"

Comment: @Narayan
getting this error message in logs but all the pods are running fine. From Nagios checked everything is green ,nothing to do with this error I think. 


                  "parameters": [
                    "VolumeBinding",
                    "node(s) had volume node affinity conflict"
                  ],
                  "messageId": "no.scale.up.mig.failing.predicate"
            
 
            },
            "reason": {
              "messageId": "no.scale.up.mig.skipped",
              "parameters": [
                "max node group size reached"
              ]

Comment: @LherbenG
only notification I am getting on console like "Can’t scale up a node pool because of a failing scheduling predicate"  and also when I hover the mouse on black round "i"  written icon just beside notification its showing "Notifications show scaling issues observed within the past 72 hours regardless of whether they’ve been resolved.  For your kind information I have upgraded successfully and no such issues on my applications or pods. everything is up and running.

Comment: Hey @Schatt, considering both the error messages "no.scale.up.mig.skipped" and "no.scale.up.mig.failing.predicate" indicates potential issue with your pod's configuration like affinity. Probably you may check this  https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-autoscaler-visibility#noscaleup-mig-level-reasons

Additionally, my advice would be to find the time when the last error log was registered, if it's long back and currently all pods are scheduled then you are good. Cuz that warning will be displayed for 72 hours irrecpetive of resolution

Comment: One more thing check the resources field of your pods, if they are requesting more than what a node can afford then it'll also cause an issue. In this case, you may enable node auto provision so that GKE can understand the request and create a new node pool to accommodate the pod. However, this requires a lot of checks so it would be better to contact the GCP support.

Comment: Please review the information regarding the no.scale.up.mig.failing.predicate in this link https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-autoscaler-visibility about Kubernetes cluster autoscaler visibility.